# Windows Server 2008 R2, Active Directory, and Oracle Database Server

Tags: oracle, windows, connectivity

I have a group of clients, Windows Server 2008 R2 (Active Directory installed on it), and an Oracle database server.

I want to know how to make the configuration of the following Diagram in this link:

[image]

How to configure the clients to reach the database server through the active directory?

If Active Directory is not of any use here, is there another way I can do remote routing from clients to the DB server through a proxy?

All I want is any way to make the connection in the diagram because I've already tried to use Oracle Connection Manager to connect the clients to the Oracle server through a proxy server but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *need* an Oracle proxy server, then you should investigate Oracle Connection Manager, which is exactly that.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/cman.htm for the documentation on 11gR1's version of it.

Comment: Oracle Connection Manager is the answer ^_^